# Rendering HTML as string from a razor file and a poco class

Tags: c#, razor, webforms

I have a simple razor file _modelTemplate.cshtml and a poco class model.
I'd like to be able to Render HTML string by passing a model to the _modelTemplate.cshtml

Reason: I'm working on a legacy WebForms application and really would just like to use razor as a templating engine to generate clean HTML for a particular section that doesn't need WebForms server controls or postbacks.

I'm not needing any MVC helpers in the Razor file, just a simple template and a model for bindings. I figured I could use razor to generate the HTML, and then bind that rendered string to a Literals's .Text property in the WebForm's .aspx page.

I'm thinking something like:

```
Lit1.Text = RenderRazorTemplateAsString(razorFilePath, model);
```

Is there a method to do this, or would I have to build out something?

Comment: controller.ViewData.Model = model;
            string result = string.Empty;
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, writer);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

                result = writer.ToString();
            }

Comment: or you simply want Html.Raw()?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you are getting at. This isn't an MVC project, but WebForms. I just need to render html from a poco model and a template. I just wish to use Razor as the engine without MVC.  So, I'm thinking I would only add references for System.Web.Razor and maybe System.Web.WebPages if needed.

Comment: Sorry then... WebForms is too classic for me..

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have an answer but am curious about the possibility.
It would seem that for Razor to work you would need to embed the view or HTML part of your page with Razor directives? for that to work you would then need to create a page with a .cshtml extension, at this point I would think you're better off with just writing out your own HTML

Comment: @DaniDev Yes, I don't mind creating the .cshtml file. That allows for creating clean html templates with module binding and that's what I'm wanting. There's not a good way to do that in WebForms, and I certainly don't want to write html server-side using string concatenation. I figured out a way in my answer below, but would love to know of any other ways/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating the following project.

I've posted it to github called [WebFormsRazor](https://github.com/bradbamford/WebFormsRazor). It does what I was looking for, it only uses Microsoft references and I can render HTML with 1 line of code.

```
Lit1.Text = RazorTemplate.Render(myModel, "template.cshtml");
```

There is 1 drawback, your razor templates must inherit from a class in the project called RazorWebPage that derives from WebPageBase.

```
@inherits WebFormsRazor.RazorWebPage<myModel>
```

Maybe that limitation could be overcome with better code, but needed a way to attach the poco class Model to the page in order to use it for the razor binding.

And maybe there is a much better way to do this, but this is how I've solved it for now, it does what I was looking for.